# VB.net Moving files from desktop

Tags: vb.net

I am in the process of making a launcher for a mod pack. I have everything I need for it to work. The question is there anyway the launcher can move things from the other users desktop after I give it to them cause I understand not everyone has the same name in their user file so is their a global way to get to someones desktop with having to change it for each person. Like my desktop is located at C:\Users\Zach\Desktop Not everyone's User file is Zach This is all the code I have at the moment. Also I am asking for help not someone to do it for me.

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseEnter
    PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.Exit_2
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseLeave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseLeave
    PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources._Exit
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.Click
    Process.Start("FILE NAME")
    MsgBox("Downloading Arma 3 Mods")
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox2_MouseEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.MouseEnter
    PictureBox2.Image = My.Resources.Download_2

End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox2_MouseLeave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.MouseLeave
    PictureBox2.Image = My.Resources.Download
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox3.Click
    Dim path As String = "c:\"
    Dim path2 As String = "c:\"

    Try
        If File.Exists(path) = False Then
            ' This statement ensures that the file is created, 
            ' but the handle is not kept. 
            Dim fs As FileStream = File.Create(path)
            fs.Close()
        End If

        ' Ensure that the target does not exist. 
        If File.Exists(path2) Then
            File.Delete(path2)
        End If

        ' Move the file.
        File.Move(path, path2)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} moved to {1}", path, path2)

        ' See if the original file exists now. 
        If File.Exists(path) Then
            Console.WriteLine("The original file still exists, which is unexpected.")
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("The original file no longer exists, which is expected.")
        End If
    Finally
    End Try
End Sub


Private Sub PictureBox3_MouseEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox3.MouseEnter
    PictureBox3.Image = My.Resources.Move_File_2
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox3_MouseLeave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox3.MouseLeave
    PictureBox3.Image = My.Resources.Move_File
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)`

Comment: Another question When i go to call to the file on the desktop what am i suppose to put after C:/

Comment: use `Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), THE_FILE_NAME)` to get a fully qualified path name to a file on the desktop

Comment: What is the path i am suppose to put on Dim path As String = "C:\"

Comment: you dont add to C:\ that code I gave you does it for you.

Comment: I replaced Dim path As String = "C:\" to the code you gave me and im getting alot of errors. Also This is the first time I have ever done anything like this.

Comment: it is the same thing as in the answer you accepted.  I have no idea how to debug "alot of errors" without seeing the code.  This question is closed, just ask a new one (they are free).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Environment.GetFolderPath Method: 
[Check full explanation here!](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

In this case, use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)` to get the desktop directory for the user.

Like this:

```
Imports System

Class Sample
   Public Shared Sub Main()
      Console.WriteLine()
      Console.WriteLine("GetFolderPath: {0}", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory))
   End Sub 'Main
End Class 'Sample
```

Comment: Where do I put this? At the moment i have it at the bottom.